# Сотрудников нет в списке модераторов

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, модерация

Вопрос короткий: Почему в [списке модераторов сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) нет сотрудников-модераторов?

Answer (score 2):

Нет сотрудников-модераторов. Есть сотрудники компании (разработчки, менеджеры сообщества) и есть модераторы (назначенные и выбранные).

Но сотрудников значительно больше, чем модераторов на одном подсайте, а вмешиваются они значительно реже. Поэтому нет особого смысла на них смотреть.

Comment: Ну у всех сотрудников, что я встречал, есть ромбик, значит они модератры, значит они сорудники-модераторы :) А то что они реже вмешиваются, как по мне слабоватый аргумент, т.к. и среди модераторов, которые в отображаемом списке, бывают те кто редко что-то делают. Можно на крайняк сделать ещё один список ниже модераторов, где будут сотрудники